# Displaying only those records which contains all the elements in a Superset for a specific column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, resultset

## Introduction

I have a database with 3 columns: -

1. `Country`
2. `Year`
3. `Electricity Generation`

**Sample table** values for your reference: -

| Country | Year | Electricity Generation (TWh) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 2000 | 0.47 |
| Afghanistan | 2001 | 0.59 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| Afghanistan | 2020 | 0.78 |
| Australia | 1985 | 123.673 |
| Australia | 1986 | 129.527 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| Australia | 2021 | 267.45227 |

The `Year` column *superset* has the *year* values between **1985 and 2021**.

## Problem Statement

I want to see the result set of only those countries which has **complete data** i.e. countries which has the data from the year **1985 till 2021**.

I am facing three types of abnormalities: -

1. Some country's `Year` value start from the year **later than 1985.**
2. Some country's `Year` value end at the year **earlier than 2021.**
3. Some country's `Year` value **start** from the year *1985* and **end** at *2021*, but has **missing year values in between** like the data for the *year 2001, 2005* etc. are **missing**.

## Desired Solution

A SQL Query which displays the data for only those countries which has all the `Year` column values (i.e. in the set of values from 1985 till 2021)

The resulting table should look something like this: -

| Country | Year | Electricity Generation (TWh) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | 1985 | 123.673 |
| Australia | 1986 | 129.527 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| Australia | 2021 | 267.45227 |
| USA | 1985 | 2657.1501 |
| USA | 1986 | 2676.1130 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| USA | 2021 | 4406.4130 |

## SQL Query Trial

The following MySQL query is what I have written till now: -

```
SELECT * 
FROM meta_generation
WHERE `Year` BETWEEN 1985 AND 2021
GROUP BY `Country`, `Year`;
```

Naturally the above query also gives me the value for the countries who suffer from the abnormalities as stated above. Please help in how to achieve my desired result set.

## Followup Question

The answer provided by @FlexYourData is correct one, but I tried to modify the query in another format which gave me the following error: -

> Error Code: 1038. Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size.

This is my modified query: -

```
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        meta_generation
    WHERE 
        `Country` IN 
            (SELECT 
                `Country`
             FROM 
                 meta_generation
             WHERE 
                 `Year` BETWEEN 1985 AND 2021
             GROUP BY 
                 `Country`
             HAVING 
                  COUNT(DISTINCT Year) = 37);
```

Why did this happen? Is using Nested Queries not a good practice?

Comment: re the following question, what type are country and year?  and what is `select version();`?  this may be a recent bug.  if not, the remedy is just to increase your sort butter size or use join.  I try to avoid IN, just because I prefer the query as written to correspond with what I want the query plan to be.

Comment: @ysth `Country` is of datatype `text` and `Year` is `Bigint(20)`. The version is `10.5.5-MariaDB`. Regarding increasing the buffer size, that is not possible since I am working on my Uni's server and admin refuses to make any changes to the config.

Comment: Try changing Country to a varchar type (using the biggest size you need for your data)

Comment: Using sub-queries as value lists for an IN statement is generally not advisable due to performance. It's better to use a join to the sub-query and if the data are very large, even better to create a temporary table and index it before joining to the main table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count distinct years per country, then select only those countries with `(2021-1985+1) = 37` years.

So,

```
WITH countries
AS
(
SELECT Country
FROM meta_generation
WHERE Year BETWEEN 1985 AND 2021
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Year) = 37
)
SELECT m.*
FROM meta_generation m 
INNER JOIN countries c ON m.Country = c.Country;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your same idea but by using nested `SELECT` statement in the `WHERE IN` condition. It gave me Error Code: 1038. Can you tell why does MySQL does not particularly like Nested Queries?

Comment: please show the entire 1038 error?  and the query that generated it